# How Long is the Longest Class in Java Source Code?

Tags: java

Just curious to know which is the longest class in Java Source Code ( any version above Java 6 ) and how many lines of code is it?

Why do I want to know, what is the use-case?

- Just curious.

IMHO, knowing this is also a good way to understand how Java adheres to SOLID principles i.e. How long was the longest class after all those effort to keep it as small as possible.

Comment: Class should be as small as possible and and according SOLID rules, the more the better is not the case....

Comment: Why don't you check yourself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because well, it just is.

Comment: What's so off-topic in learning things from the source-code? I pray more people in SO be kind hearted as the the person who just helped me with an elegant way of looking it up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
jdk1.8.0/src> wc -l **/*.java | sort -n | tail -n 2

  10159 java/awt/Component.java
```

Other example are `ORBUtilSystemException` which is 9063 lines long, `Character` is 7231 lines, `BigDecimal` is 5224 lines. These probably shouldn't be used as examples of good design but what might happen in large projects over time. The average line count is 310.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name '*.java' | xargs wc -l | sort -nr | head -n 10
```

Result for `jdk1.8.0`:

```
10161 ./awt/Component.java
 7231 ./lang/Character.java
 6312 ./util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java
 5858 ./util/regex/Pattern.java
 5564 ./util/Collections.java
 5257 ./math/BigDecimal.java
 5115 ./util/Arrays.java
 4986 ./awt/Container.java
 4698 ./util/Formatter.java
```

Note that the shorter idiom `wc -l **/*.java` is not recursive by default. You need to `shopt -s globstar` to make the operator recursive. Without that you'll miss large classes such as,

```
6312 ./util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java
4503 ./time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java
```

**Note for mac users:**
For the accepted answer to work (`wc -l **/*.java`), you need bash with `globstar` support (`≥ 4.x`). macOS Catalina, for example, comes with an older version of bash (`3.2.57`). In that case you need to install bash with Homebrew (`brew install bash`), and turn on recursiveness with `shopt -s globstar`. You can find more details [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/291290/328523).